# Change order of services during startup or login

Tags: startup, services

I've read of ways to change startup services' order of execution for Ubuntu. I'm hoping it's possible and simple to do it in macOS as well. I was thinking something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753922/how-to-change-the-order-of-execution-of-services-at-startup). My objective is to ensure my wifi has time to connect after logging in before any other startup services or apps run that requires an active internet connection.

Maybe a scripted startup service that is forced to run before other startup services to ensure the network is active before allowing other processes to run? Or a simple prioritization of startup services and lock progression to the next service until a specified service reaches an acceptable state?

I'm not very familiar with MacOS, so any pointers in this direction would be amazing.

Comment: Wifi should certainly be active before any user processes.

Comment: @benwiggy it's my work laptop so it goes through GlobalProtect and Enterprise Connect upon login. I always get issues with those and attempts to automatically connect to things like shared drives. I want these to wait for the wifi service to completely boot up and maybe even a delay before allowing the next processes.

Comment: I've used [DelayedLauncher](https://www.taoeffect.com/blog/2011/01/delayedlauncher-2-2/) in the past. So you basically remove everything or everything that matters from the startup items, put this in the startup items and put everything you want delayed in this app. Just drag applications in the window. Some background applications may be challenging to find cause those are usually kinda hidden in the application folder. I've mostly used this to make an old laptop startup a little faster by running apps I don't need to use immediately (like say dropbox) with like a few minutes of delay.